# solve: VBA for each code

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach

Trying to loop through a range and highlight a group of cells if one cell in that group is a certain word. It will get through the first row of groups and highlight correctly and then wont loop down to next row.

```
Sub status()

Dim cell As Object

For Each cell In range("A10:R285")

If cell.Value = "Available" Then
    cell.Offset(-2, 0).Interior.Color = 5287936
    cell.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.Color = 5287936
    cell.Interior.Color = 5287936
    cell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = 5287936
End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

It highlights `"if cell.value = "available" then"` line and says error type mismatch

Comment: Try `Dim cell As Range`

Comment: @TimWilliams good point but not strictly necessary :)

Comment: Why don't you use conditional formatting instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub status()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A10:R285")
    If Not IsError(cell.Value) Then
    If cell.Value = "Available" Then
        cell.Offset(-2, 0).Resize(4,1).Interior.Color = 5287936
    End If
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```